# How can I scroll a custom layout and lazycolumn in the same row as if they are one component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-gesture

I have a row that contains a lazycolumn and a custom layout. The lazy column contains the hours and a custom layout containing events positioned. They have different scroll states, so they won't scroll together. How can I fix this. Cause I need a lazycolumnn to track the day I am in using the layout info.

```
@Composable
fun ScheduleSidebar(
    hourHeight: Dp = 64.dp){
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier,
    
    ) {
        val startTime = LocalTime.MIN
        items(168) { hour ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.height(hourHeight)) {
                Text(startTime.plusHours(hour.toLong()))
            }
        
        }

    }
```

This is my view:

```
@Composable
fun ScheduleView(
    viewModel: ScheduleViewModel = getViewModel()
) {
    val verticalScrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val ss = rememberLazyListState()
    val scrollConnection = rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()

     //added this and still the lazycolumn can scroll alone

LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {



   var oldValue = 0
    snapshotFlow {
        verticalScrollState.value
    }.collect {
        println("Value: $it")
        ss.scrollBy((it-oldValue).toFloat())
        oldValue = it
    }
}


    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {


        ScheduleHeader()

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        ) {

            ScheduleSidebar(
                hourHeight = 64.dp,
                modifier = Modifier
               
                ,
             
            
          
            )

            Schedule(
                bookings = viewModel.state.value.bookingsList,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(verticalScrollState),
            
           
                onEmptyViewClicked = { days, hour, selectedDate ->
                    showSheet = true
                    viewModel.onEvent(
                        ScheduleEvent.OnEmptyViewClicked(
                            days = days,
                            startTime = hour,
                            selectedDate = selectedDate
                        )
                    )

                }
            )
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
val state = rememberScrollState()
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {

    var oldValue = 0
    snapshotFlow {
        state.value
    }.collect {
        println("Value: $it")
        lazyListState.scrollBy((it -oldValue).toFloat())

        oldValue = it
    }
}
```

to scroll LazyColumn when Column with vertical scroll is scrolled.

Since it's not reproducible or no image for expected result, made a sample to show that how you can scroll using ones value

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun LayoutTest() {

    val state = rememberScrollState()
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {

        var oldValue = 0
        snapshotFlow {
            state.value
        }.collect {
            println("Value: $it")
            lazyListState.scrollBy((it - oldValue).toFloat())

            oldValue = it
        }
    }

    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
    ) {


        Row(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .border(3.dp, Color.Green)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(150.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .verticalScroll(state = state)
            ) {
                for (i in 0..99) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Header $i",
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        color = Color.White,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.Green)
                    )
                }
            }

            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                state = lazyListState
            ) {
                items(100) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Row $it",
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        color = Color.White,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.Red)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

If you wish to scroll both scrollable Column and LazyColumn together NestedScrollConnection can be used to get scroll value of LazyColumn and scroll stat to disable LaunchedEffect that listens Column scroll to not scroll LazyColumn further.

However this doesn't work properly if you start scrolling while scroll in other Composable is in progress.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun LayoutTest() {

    val state = rememberScrollState()
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    var listScrolling by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                val delta = -available.y
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    state.scrollBy(delta)
                    listScrolling = true
                }
                return Offset.Zero
            }

            override suspend fun onPostFling(consumed: Velocity, available: Velocity): Velocity {
                listScrolling = false
                return super.onPostFling(consumed, available)
            }
        }
    }


    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        var oldValue = 0
        snapshotFlow {
            state.value
        }.collect {
            if (listScrolling.not() && lazyListState.isScrollInProgress.not()) {
                lazyListState.scrollBy((it - oldValue).toFloat())
                oldValue = it
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {

        Row(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(150.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .verticalScroll(state = state)
            ) {
                for (i in 0..400) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Header $i",
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .shadow(4.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .wrapContentSize()
                    )
                }
            }


            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection),
                state = lazyListState
            ) {
                items(401) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Row $it",
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .shadow(4.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .wrapContentSize()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit2

This one seem like works well in any condition

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun LayoutTest2() {

    val state = rememberScrollState()
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                val delta = -available.y
                if (state.isScrollInProgress.not()) {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        state.scrollBy(delta)
                    }
                }

                if (lazyListState.isScrollInProgress.not()) {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        lazyListState.scrollBy(delta)
                    }
                }
                return Offset.Zero
            }

        }
    }

    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {

        Row(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(150.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .verticalScroll(state = state)
            ) {
                for (i in 0..400) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Header $i",
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .shadow(4.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .wrapContentSize()
                    )
                }
            }

            LazyColumn(
                state = lazyListState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                items(401) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Row $it",
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .shadow(4.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .wrapContentSize()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sill the lazycolumn can scroll alone if I am scrolling it not the scrolling the custom layout. Aka the green layout is scrolling alone if I scroll it, but if I scroll the red layout the green layout scrolls with it.

Comment: any idea how can we fix it please??

Comment: Would you mind going over it again, i didn't understand how it should be. You want scrolling green area to scroll red area right? You don't want red area(LazyColumn) to be not scrollable or you want Green area to scroll when red area is scrolled?

Comment: yes i want them to both scroll together always, now only when I scroll the red area the green area is scrolled synchronously with it, but it is not the case when I scroll the green area, the red are stays in the same position. Green area: lazycolumn, Red: Custom Layout. Thanks again for your valuable help!!!

Comment: In that case you need to write another LaunchedEffect for lazyListState but this time you need to add boolean flags to not collect one that is being scrolled already. I will post example for this when i'm available

Comment: Thanks man, you will save me. I have been stuck for 2 weeks on this

Comment: Updated answer but this also goes out of sync sometimes for instance when you scroll list while scroll from Column is in progress

Comment: Edit 2 worked perfectly, I just want to check the recomposition count, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You still might need some tweaks in some conditions though. Also i tested with 2 LaunchedEffects  one observing lazyStateList.firstVisibleItemOffset as in my original answer you can also keep that in mind too but i think more versatile one is the one in edit 2

Comment: thanks a  lot man!! I will use it for now, if I face any issue I will come back to you