# Compose Grid layout span rows/cols

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

How to leverage `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid` (or something else) to create something like this?

[image]

I want everything to be scrollable.
I will always have one Red and one Blue. The number of Green can be thousands. So when I scroll down, I will only have a column of green on the right and nothing on the left.

This is what I tried:

```
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
        columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
        verticalItemSpacing = 4.dp,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        item(
            span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }
        item(
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.Green)
                )
            }
        }
        items(100) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            )
        }
    }
```

But the green will place themselves below the Blue which is not the expected behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid` positioning elements after other whether they are in `item` or `items` is expected behavior as with other `LazyLists` do the same.

Assigning `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` literally does nothing other than calling layout and measure twice in your case. It's useful when a Composable has child Composables that it can call layout phase twice to get intrinsic size calculations to determine which height to use.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements

You can add only one element, which is LazyColumn, for blue section that is not measured with Constraints.Infinity. For that, you can either get maxHeight of screen via `BoxWithConstraints` or  `LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp` minus padding and height of red if you want and set a max height for a `Constraints` with not infinite `maxHeight`.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {
    BoxWithConstraints {

        val height = maxHeight

        val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp

        LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
            columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
            verticalItemSpacing = 4.dp,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            item(
                span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.Red)
                )
            }
            item(
            ) {
                Box {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(200.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.Green)
                    )
                }
            }
            item {
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .heightIn(max = height - 100.dp - 4.dp)
                        .border(2.dp, Color.Magenta),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                ) {
                    items(100) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(100.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .background(Color.Blue)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `Modifier.height` instead of `Modifier.heightIn` if `LazyColumn` is supposed to occupy screenHeigh - padding - red element height independent of how many items it will have. heightIn makes sure that it will grow only up to this height.

### Edit

If you wish to scroll left item as well you can assign height that is total height of blue rectangles + sum spaces between each item

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test2() {

    val itemCount = 100
    val itemHeight = 100.dp
    val verticalItemSpacing = 4.dp
    val leftItemHeight = itemHeight * itemCount + verticalItemSpacing * (itemCount - 1)


    LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
        columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
        verticalItemSpacing = verticalItemSpacing,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {


        item(
            span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }
        item {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.height(leftItemHeight)) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.Green)
                )
            }
        }
        items(100) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {
                SideEffect {
                    println("Composing $it")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
However with your solution the blue items are dissociated from the green part: only the blue part is scrolling. I'm looking to looks like the blue and the green are scrolling at the same time, so the green disappear as the blue are scrolling. But with your version is a better start, I will try to iterate on it.

Comment: Also this is like scroll within a scroll right. something like recyclerview within recyclerview both scrolling in same direction which is kind of discouraged right?

Comment: @Raghunandan no it's not discouraged. Let's say you want to have 100.dp scrollable area in GridLayout, how will you do it? you need to add a LazyColumn with 100.dp height to do it. The issue is if you don't assign a maxConstraints via height or heightIn it will throw exception because scroll which is available in LazyLists throws exception when maxHeight or maxWidth ,depending on scroll direction, is Constrants.Infinity

Comment: @stankocken you can use it as in edited section. Instead of `IntrinsicSize.Max` you assign total height by calculating sum of blue item height and spaces between them. Intrinsics are used for calculating child composables to get optimum height/width to set parent COmposable accordingly

Comment: this is a neat trick. I was actually trying to offset items based on span but that does not work well with LazyGrid.

Comment: This is actually what OP was trying to do with `IntrinsicSize.Max`. Other option is to use `NestedScrollConnection`` and change `Offset` of green box

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Calculating the sum of the items is not something easy if the items don't have a fixed height. Also, if I can calculate the sum of the items, I can just keep my initial proposition (only one LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid) and having the green item taking this size, to avoid the double lazy list/grid.

Comment: @stankocken you will go with other option then. You will not set height for green item but change its offset via nested scroll. You can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76930102/how-can-i-scroll-a-custom-layout-and-lazycolumn-in-the-same-row-as-if-they-are-o/76931668#76931668. You just need to increase y position of green item as blue items are scrolled in `LazyColumn` as in my first answer