How do I sync the scrolling of two different LazyColumn, so that when one is scrolled, the other scrolls in sync
I am building a measurement entry page where a single column(left side lazy column) is general and it corelates with three other segments(right side lazy column inside a pager). so i added those three segments in a horizontal pager. the first column(left side) is general and stays visible and the user can move between the three segments(right side) and enter corresponding values. i want to achieve a synced scroll between the first lazy column and the visible(current) lazy column from the horizontal pager component
I tried to create a single rememberlazyliststate() and distribute it between them and it didn't work. it seemed possible to use launched effect to make scrolls across all components. but i was hoping to find if there was a better approach.
@Stable
data class EntryState(
    val id: Int = 0,
)

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Entry(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
//    val entryState by entryModel.entryState.collectAsState()
    val entryState = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(EntryState())
    }
    repeat(100) { entryState.add(EntryState(id = entryState.last().id + 1)) }
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState() // scrollstate that is shared with two lazycolumns
    Row(
        modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xFFededf4))
    ) {
        StaticColumn(Modifier.weight(0.35f), entries = entryState, scrollState)
        SwipeableColumnSet(Modifier.weight(0.65f), entries = entryState, scrollState)
    }
}

@Composable
fun StaticColumn(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, entries: SnapshotStateList<EntryState>, scrollState: LazyListState) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier,
        scrollState // second instance
    ) {
        item { Box(modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)) { Text(text = "Length", fontSize = 20.sp) } }
        items(
            items = entries,
            key = { entry -> entry.id }
        ) { entry ->
            Box(
                modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .shadow(
                        elevation = 4.dp,
                        spotColor = Color.White,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                    )
                    .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 1.dp)
            ) { Text(text = "${entry.id}") }
        }
    }
}



@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SwipeableColumnSet(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, entries: SnapshotStateList<EntryState>, scrollState: LazyListState) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(1) { 3 }

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Yellow)
    ) { page ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable { }
        ) {
            when (page) {
                0 -> Column() { }
                1 -> Column(modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    Text(text = "Side Berms", fontSize = 20.sp, modifier= Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp))
                    Row {
                        Text("Left", modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 1.dp)
                            .weight(1f))
                        Text("Right", modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 1.dp)
                            .weight(1f))
                    }
                    LazyColumn(
                        modifier = modifier,
                        scrollState // second instance
                    ) {
                        items(
                            items = entries,
                            key = { entry -> entry.id }
                        ) { entry ->
                            Box(
                                modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .shadow(
                                        elevation = 4.dp,
                                        spotColor = Color.White,
                                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                                    )
                                    .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 1.dp)
                            ) {
                                Row {
                                    Text(text = "${entry.id}",
                                        Modifier
                                            .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 1.dp)
                                            .weight(1f))
                                    Text(text = "${entry.id}",
                                        Modifier
                                            .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 1.dp)
                                            .weight(1f))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                2 -> Column() { }
            }
        }
    }
}


This question is similar to: How to sync LazyColumn scroll in HorizontalPager - Jetpack Compose. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@BenjyTec It is similar to what i want. I have an additional column which is static(left side) while the pages in horizontal pager(right side) needs to be synced with that static column. if a global scroll state is maintained then it is possible is whats answered there while also saying scrolltoitem is blocking sometimes. so i was looking for a more concrete answer.

You can do it using NestedScrollConnection. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76931668/5457853
